# What is the correct operation to compute feature crosses on equal size vectors?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering

In working through Google's [Machine Learning Crash Course](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/feature-crosses/crossing-one-hot-vectors), I am a little stuck in my understanding of the concept of feature crosses for one-hot encoded features.

For example, they take two binned values:

```
binned_latitude = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
binned_longitude = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

and combine them to get "a 25-element one-hot vector (24 zeroes and 1 one)". According to the course, the name feature crosses is taken from the cross product, but my understanding is that the cross product doesn't work for arbitrarily shaped vectors.

I am able to get a correct-looking result by using numpy's outer function and flattening the result, but is this the correct way to do a feature cross?

```
>>> x = np.outer(binned_latitude, binned_longitude).flatten()
>>> x.shape
(25,)
>>> x
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's correct. A flattened outer product gives you one entry for each pair of features from two vectors.

So, if you had two vectors that represented the classes (Car, Truck, Boat), and (Honda, Ford, Suzuki), feature crossing them is a way to get a one-hot encoding of

((Car, Honda), (Car, Ford), (Car, Suzuki), (Truck, Honda), (Truck, Ford), (Truck, Suzuki), (Boat, Honda), (Boat, Ford), (Boat, Suzuki)).